# How can I set the loglevel for the requests module using a dictConfig?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-3.4

I am moving from a `fileConfig` based logger to a `dictConfig` based one. I am setting the log level for requests to `WARNING`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simpleFormatter': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)-30s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            'datefmt' : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'consoleHandler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'NOTSET',
            'formatter': 'simpleFormatter',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stderr',
        },
    },
    ...
    'requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool': {
        'handlers': ['consoleHandler'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': False,
    },

import logging
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

The same thing was working with a `fileConfig`:

```
[logger_requests]
level=WARNING
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
propagate=0
```

How can I set the `loglevel` for the requests module using a `dictConfig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, beginner's error. The logger configuration must be inside the `'loggers'` key for a `dictConfig`, as explained in [the schema documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema). I was putting it at the top-level.

An error message from `dictConfig` would have been helpful, but it silently ignores any non-supported key.

Comment: It ignores non-supported keys because you can use them to extend the configuration, as documented in https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#access-to-internal-objects

Comment: @VinaySajip: Thanks, I didn't know that.